# reCaptcha issue, PHP notice index not defined

Tags: php, forms, recaptcha

I am trying to add Googles reCaptcha to my webpage form but I am having trouble. For some reason I have been getting a "undefined variable" error on the $captcha variable, and "undefined index" for the 'g-recaptcha-response'.

```
<?php
require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$name = $_REQUEST['names'];
$number = $_REQUEST['cell'];
$email = $_REQUEST['email'];
$message = $_REQUEST['message'];
$captcha = null;

if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])){
   $captcha=$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
   echo 'RESPONSE RECEIVED';
}

if(!$captcha){
    echo 'RESPONSE NOT RECEIVED';
    echo '<h2>Please check the the captcha form.</h2>';
    exit;
}
```

Here is a snippet of the HTMl form:

```
<form  name="contact form" method="POST" action="sendemail_1.php" id="main-contact-form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text"  name="name" id="names" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="email"  name="email" id="emails" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text"  name="number" id="numbers" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Number">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <textarea name="message" id="messages" required="required" class="form-control" rows="8" placeholder="Your text here"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LeVTyIUAAAAAHsB-2XIbO8x59nqi2yhesv98Xo7"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-submit" value="Submit">
    </div>
</form>
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

this

```
if(!$captcha){
    echo 'RESPONSE NOT RECEIVED';
    echo '<h2>Please check the the captcha form.</h2>';
    exit;
}
```

should be this

```
if(!isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']))){
    echo 'RESPONSE NOT RECEIVED';
    echo '<h2>Please check the the captcha form.</h2>';
    exit;
}
```

Because $captcha doesn't exist if the first if fail

Comment: Awesome! That looks like it worked for that issue, but now I am getting another issue. Undefined index: cell, Undefined index: names. Any idea what could be causing this? It worked before I added the reCaptcha code. Thanks!

Comment: in which line is thronw this warning? because the rest of the code seems ok.

Comment: lines 4 and 5...i have literally no idea ->  PHP Notice:  Undefined index: cell in /var/app/current/sendemail_1.php on line 5 -> PHP Notice:  Undefined index: names in /var/app/current/sendemail_1.php on line 4